# Open Source parcel tracking project for Linux

Tags: linux, open-source, server

I sometimes order a parcel from Aliexpress and other sites. And to track the parcels I use a third-party site. To increase confidentiality, I would like to store information about tracked parcels only in my computer.
Is there any Open Source project to track the parcels under Linux?